# Button Function one time

Tags: javascript, html, function, button

So I am trying to create a page where one can change the background with colorPicker. And it does work, only if I change it, I cannot change it again without refreshing the page. For instance, I changed the BGCR to red, but to change it to Yellow I have to refresh the page. SO what can I do to make it work? here is the code:

```js
const color = document.getElementById('colorPick').value
document.getElementById('changeColor').onclick = changeCol

function changeCol() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color
}
```

```html
<input id="changeColor" type="button" value="Change the Color">
<input type="color" id="colorPick">
```

Answer (score 1):

When you write:

```
const color = document.getElementById('colorPick').value;
```

you're immediately picking up the color value rather than caching the element which means you can't use it again.

Instead do:

```
const color = document.getElementById('colorPick');
```

and in your function just assign `color.value` to the background.

```js
const color = document.getElementById('colorPick');
document.getElementById('changeColor').onclick = changeCol;

function changeCol() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color.value;
}
```

```html
<input id="changeColor" type="button" value="Change the Color">
<input type="color" id="colorPick">
```

Answer (score 0):

As a second solution, **if you want** you could remove the button which is not required to change the color.

```js
const color = document.getElementById('colorPick');

function changeCol() {
  document.body.style.backgroundColor = color.value;
}
```

```html
<input type="color" id="colorPick" onchange="changeCol()">
```